# CSS, change background-color to compensate container background-color

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I want to apply a background-color on an image to put a shadow on it.

Nothing very peculiar for now, I simply put `background-color:rgba(23,23,23,0.88);` in my CSS.

But on this image, I need to have an other div, who display the real image without the shadow on it and I don't know how I can do it.

I made a fiddle because it must not be very clear: https://jsfiddle.net/Haplo31/aguxfr67/

In this fiddle, I would need to have the blue div "content" displaying the part of the image below without the background-color of the bgContainer, like a window on the image. (I don't need the blue color at all, it's just to highlight the div for the example)

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot for your time and your help

Comment: So you want a part that has no shadow?

Comment: Or you want to display the whole image inside that div?

Comment: I simply want a part with no shadow

Answer (score 0):

You could be using the `box-shadow` property, which comes in pretty handy in situations like this. I modified your `bg-container` class and added a `:before` selector to apply the shadow.

Text can be inserted through the `content` css-attribute, you could also create another div-class, apply the same positioning properties and fuel your text into that.

```css
.imgContainer {
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoR1aeLhVEeg-rfmWln8uuNI7t0El3zNY8HHfKT1Qwd2oN8-GPQQ');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bgContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgContainer:before {
  content: 'This is some sample text to demonstrate you can get content as well';
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;

  box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px black;
  opacity: 0.88;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <div class="bgContainer">
    <!--<div class="content">
    </div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```